# How to manage same session using JWT token & openssl on different servers like 1 app on CI4 and other is on Laravel? Token should be worked accross

Tags: session, codeigniter-4, laravel-10

We have application on Codeigniter and api on Laravel. We create token and shared to Api end. it would not work because laravel does not create session or verify the token created from Codeigniter.

https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/ on laravel end

Codeigniter side login and returns jwt token with custom payload and encrypted with openssl. we use this token on laravel api side.